# Light Weight Bluetooth LE library in C

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluetooth-gatt, gatttool, gattlib

I have been looking around for a simple Bluetooth LE library in C that allows me to scan for BLE devices, connect and receive periodic notifications from a given service UUID from the BLE device. Something that directly works with Bluetooth sockets and libbluetooth(created from BlueZ) and not using DBUS. Pairing and security functionality are not required.

Came across https://github.com/labapart/gattlib. Appears to be good but uses dbus API and has dependency on libdbus, glib, so on. To use this library, there is an additional 5MB of libraries required, hence decided to go without dbus. We do not have space on our device to support 5MB of bluetooth stack on compressed rootfs image. The total size of our rootfs image is 9 MB. The bluetooth stack with dbus itself appears to be more than 50% of our rootfs size.

There is also - https://github.com/edrosten/libblepp which is in c++ and doesn't use dbus. This would require to write a C wrapper to be used in C programs and also overhead of C++ constructs such as compiler generated copy constructors, assignment operators and so on. Also issues in cross-compiling.

Target board is Xilinx Zynq running Linux  and the build system is buildroot.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution, it may be of help for someone...

After searching and going through Linux Conference and IOT conference videos on youtube, figured that Bluez has light weight executables and the code is present in src/shared folder of Bluez. For btgattclient.c produces "gatt-client" executable when compiled which does the same functionality as "gatttool" and is not dependant on bluetoothd or dbus. The only dependency it has is on glib-2.0.

This is helpful if we need lightweight tools when the OS has no bluetoothd running or has no dbus library installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use BlueZ for BLE communication, the only supported API is the D-Bus API. Everything else is either discouraged or deprecated.

If you want something more minimal and/or not use BlueZ at all, you can use the `HCI_CHANNEL_USER` feature in Linux to get raw access to the HCI connection in the kernel. With this you can use any Bluetooth Host stack software or write your own minimal if you only require an extremely small subset.

Questions asking for software library recommendations are not allowed on Stack Overflow due to the possibility for opinion-based results though.